# trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given, Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm coding an e-commerce website with Wordpress. This website should display a specific product for a specific user

```
$Class = get_field('nomUtilisateur');

            $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' =>-1,
                    'meta_key' => $Class['ID'],
                    'meta_value' => $current_user,
                    );

       $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
       if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {

                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                            $Class = get_field('nomUtilisateur');
                                    if($Class['ID'] == $current_user->ID){



                                            wc_get_template_part( 'content' );



                                    }
                    endwhile;

            } else {
                    echo __( 'No products found' );
            }
```

I actually have this error :

> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-meta-query.php on line 613

And nothing is showing up

Thank you

Comment: There is no `trim` in the code you have shown.

Comment: @user3783243 that's the point. But you can see that it is coming from wp-meta-query.php of the wordpress includes. If there was a stack trace you would likely see it coming from where the WP_Query constructor is called or the instance used.

Comment: @slepic The question title is about the `trim` function. I guess OP is misusing some WP function, not really a PHP question.

Comment: @user3783243 Well, technically, he didn't ask any question at all. He just got a warning and doesn't know what it means, so basicaly he wanted to ask what might be causing it or how to get rid of it... It is related to PHP because it is written in PHP. Yes he is passing wrong arguments to a wordpress function/class constructor. But his biggest struggle is that PHP warnings are not shown with stack trace, like exception would. If he could see the trace he would probably not need to ask anything...

Comment: @slepic Well, editing `$meta_value = trim( $meta_value );` so it handles an object I don't think is the answer, likely future versions will have the same issue. The WP usage should be altered, not the PHP framework.

Comment: @user3783243 Honestly, what are you even talking about? The guy had problem with trim somewhere inside wp internals. Who's suggesting to solve the problem by trimming something in advance here? Not me...

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `$current_user` to WP_Query constructor. Try `$current_user->ID` or whatever field you really need there.